# matching common strings between two data sets

Tags: string, algorithm, search, dictionary

I am working on a website conversion. I have a dump of the database backend as an sql file. I also have a scrape of the website from wget.

What I'm wanting to do is map database tables and columns to directories, pages, and sections of pages in the scrape. I'd like to automate this.

Is there some tool or a script out there that could pull strings from one source and look for them in the other? Ideally, it would return a set of results that would say soemthing like

```
string "piece of website content here" on line 453 in table.sql matches string in website.com/subdirectory/certain_page.asp on line 56.
```

I don't want to do line comparisons because lines from the database dump (`INSERT INTO table VALUES (...)` ) aren't going to match lines in the page where it actually populates (`<div id='left_column'><div id='left_content'>...</div></div>`).

I realize this is a computationally intensive task, but even letting it run over the weekend is fine.

I've found similar questions, but I don't have enough CS background to know if they are identical to my problem or not. SO kindly suggested [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096991/matching-two-large-sets-of-strings-in-c), but it appears to be dealing with a known set of needles to match against the haystack. In my case, I need to compare haystack to haystack, and see matching straws of hay.

Is there a command-line script or command out there, or is this something I need to build? If I build it, should I use the Aho–Corasick algorithm, as suggested in the other question?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem a bit?  Are you allowed to preprocess the two dump files so that you eliminate the unnecessary formatting?  Are you looking for complete DB row matches, or just strings in one that appear in the other ?

Comment: I can process the files a little bit. That would be easy for the database dump, but harder if not impossible for the website files, because I can't assume they're well structured. But if my program can do string matching, why bother putting any work into cleaning up the files? I just want the mappings.

Comment: I'm just looking for string matches. `Line 12 of file A has string "piece of content" that matches line 45 of file B`

Comment: It might be nice to clean up the files, since that way you won't find spurious matches between junk strings containing a mixture of formatting and actual text.  However, if this isn't a concern, then you're absolutely right and you don't need to do this step.

Comment: I don't see any likelihood of spurious matches. The sqldump isn't going to have HTML as metadata. But if it does have that as field data -- which would mean page content is being stored in the database -- I will want to know about it as a match! And the web page files aren't going to have DDL or DCL as content.

Answer (score 1):

So your two questions are 1) Is there already a solution that will do what you want, and 2) Should you use the Aho-Corasick algorithm.

The first answer is that I doubt you'll find a ready-built tool that will meet your needs.
The second answer is that, since you don't care about performance and have a limited CS background, that you should use whatever algorithm you find simplest to implement.

I will go one step further and propose an architecture.

First, you need to be able to parse the .sql files into a meaningful way, one that go line-by-line and return tablename, column_name, and value.  A StreamReader is probably best for this.

Second, you need a parser for your webpages that will go element-by-element and return each text node and the name of each parent element all the way up to the html element and its parent filename.  An XmlTextReader or similar streaming XML parser, such as SAXON is probably best, as long as it will operate on non-valid XML.

You would need to tie these two parsers together with a mutual search algorithm of some sort.  You will have to customize it to suit your needs.  Aho-Corasick will apparently get you the best performance if you can pull it off.  A naive algorithm is easy to implement, though, and here's how:

Assuming you have your two parsers that loop through each field (on the one hand) and each text node (on the other hand), pick one of the two parsers and have it go through each of the strings in its data source, calling the other parser to search the other data source for all possible matches, and logging the ones it finds.

Comment: I think it would be best to parse a dictionary out of the sqldump, since I'm assuming that at least some parts of it are populating the website, and then match that dictionary against the website scrape.

Comment: I was thinking of using beautiful soup to parse the html -- do you have any thoughts of that against saxon?

Comment: Beautiful Soup is supposed to be much slower than lxml, as it uses regex to dig through the element soup.  If you're a regex wiz then go for it, although I think you're going to need a more XPath-oriented approach to get to where you're trying to go in the end.

Comment: @user151841 - you should post your answer and accept it.  The Dictionary approach is much better.  Go through your SQL and make a dictionary of each word you find.  The key is the word you found.  The value is a list of tuple(databaseName, tableName, fieldName, primaryKeyOrRowIndex).  Every time you get a new hit on that key, add a new tuple to its list.  You can then search through each text node in the html files and scan them for matches in the dictionary, and when you find one, record all the database tuples you took down along with the filename and xpath to the node that matched.  Nice!

Comment: Or use a double-dictionary approach - in addition to indexing the SQL, index the HTML by going through each file and recording each word in each text node as the key to the dictionary, and the value would be a list of tuple(filename, xpath) of each word in your html files, so every time you get a new hit on a word, just add a new tuple to its list.  Then you just loop through the keys of one of the dictionaries to find matches in the other dictionary, and when you do, you record the list of tuples in both dictionaries.

Comment: Aw shucks, I can't turn down someone telling me I know what I'm doing :S I would like to post an answer with a script, so I'll see if that'll happen in the next few weeks.

Answer (score -1):

This cannot work, at least not reliably. Best case: you would fit every piece of data to its counterpart in your HTML files, but you would have many false positives. For example user names that are actual words etc.

Furthermore text is often manipulated before it is displayed. Sites often capitalize titles or truncate texts for preview etc.

AFAIK there is no such tool, and in my opinion there cannot exist one that solves your problem adequately.

Your best choice is to get the source code the site uses/used and analyze it. If that fails/is not possible you have to analyse the database manually. Get as much content as possible from the URL and try to fit the puzzle.

Comment: I don't care if usernames are actual words; I just care if they appear on the in both the website and database dump.

Comment: My point is: "Hello to my super Hello World programm..." would match against a possible username "hello" 2 times and semantically this is false. Sorry to disappoint you pal. I just wanted to save you time searching for the holy grail, but whatever.

Comment: That'd be a match that I'd like to know about. If the string 'Hello', which is not DDL, DCL, nor an SQL keyword, is appearing in the database, I want to see what it matches on the website. I can skim through a list of false matches much faster than I can compare the sqldump to site scrape, which is what you propose doing instead.